# How to change VM Public IP address without stopping the VM

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ip

When I click "Stop" button in the VM dashboard I'm getting this "Public IP address 'IP address' will be lost if this VM is stopped". What I want to do is lose the IP in order to have a new IP without stopping the VM and starting it again to achieve it. Is this possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Public IP address of your VM, without stopping it, the following steps will help

1. Login to your Azure tenant with PowerShell
2. I hope, you already have a VM with a public IP address assigned. So, un-assign the public IP

   ```bsh
   $nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name vmpub1930 -ResourceGroup manurg1
   $nic.IpConfigurations.publicipaddress.id = $null
   Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
   ```
3. Create a New Public IP

   ```
   az network nic ip-config update --name ipconfig1 --nic-name vmpub1930  --resource-group MANURG1  --public-ip-address myVMPublicIP
   ```
4. Assign the new Public IP to the VM

   ```
   az network nic ip-config update --name ipconfig1 --nic-name vmpub1930  --resource-group MANURG1  --public-ip-address myVMPublicIP
   ```

Comment: Seems like you are mixing both Azure PowerShell and Azure CLI. Thats fine, but it might be good to also show two separate solutions, just in case future readers cannot use both.

Comment: You are right ! I am a newbie here..StackOverflow is a place where we get fast solutions. On that sense, I thought of providing a quick solution. But I will make sure perfect posts going forward !

Comment: Thanks for helping me!